# C++ char pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Why does the following happen?

```
char str[10]="Pointers";
char *ptr=str;  
cout << str << "\n"; // Output : Pointers
int abc[2] = {0,1 };
int *ptr1 = abc;
cout <<ptr1 << "\n"; // But here the output is an address.
                     // Why are the two outputs different?
```

Comment: Please include your code as formatted text, not as an image.

Comment: That doesnt make any difference i guess

Comment: What doesn't make a difference? It makes it easier for us to help you, since we can copy the code and try to run it ourselves if necessary.

Comment: Sorry i didnt knew that i am not a regular user.

Comment: Which is why you should listen to our advice and not just assume that it "doesn't make any difference".

Comment: Please replace your image with actual code.

Comment: Do you actually have a " " Space between the two "<" symbols in your last line?  "cout < <"

Comment: Please read this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Please reread: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question. Specifically, how to include code, and only asking 1 question per question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, the reason for the empty space is because you asked it to print out `str[3]`, which contains a space character.

Your second question seems to be asking why there's a difference between printing a `char*` (it prints the string) and `int*` (it just prints the address). `char*` is treated as a special case, it's assumed to represent a C-style string; it prints all the characters starting at that address until a trailing null byte.

Other types of pointers might not be part of an array, and even if they were there's no way to know how long the array is, because there's no standard terminator. Since there's nothing better to do for them, printing them just prints the address value.

Comment: Quibble: a `char*` value is assumed to *point to* a C-style string, not to *be* a C-style string. Strings are not pointers.

Comment: I changed it to _represent_, which is more abstract.

Answer (score 2):

1) because `str[3]` is a space so `char * ptr = str+3` points to a space character

2) The << operator is overloaded, the implementation is called depending on argument type:

- a pointer to an int (`int*`) uses the default pointer implementation and outputs the formatted address
- a pointer to a char (`char*`) is specialized, output is formated as a null terminated string from the value it points to. If you want to output the adress, you must cast it to `void*`

Comment: oh my bad.. And any thoughts about second part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

The empty space is actually Space character after "LAB". You print the space character between "LAB" and "No 5".

Your second question: You see address, because ptr1 is actually address (pointer):

```
int *ptr1;
```

If you want to see it's first member (0), you should print *ptr1